# compare two group string,return different results

Tags: python

I run this [command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fojMC.png) in python console:

why the 2 results are different?

```
>>>S1 = 'HelloWorld'
>>>S2 = 'HelloWorld'
>>>S1 is S2
True
>>>S1 = 'Hello World'
>>>S2 = 'Hello World'
>>>S1 is S2
False                ---------i think the result is True,why it is False
```

Comment: That's a common behaviour. See the following thread: [Identity testing vs Equality testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce)

Comment: In particular, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1504848/5014455) from the duplicate.

Comment: While running code with **pycharm,** in both the cases it gives `true`

Answer (score 0):

`is` the result will be true only if the object is the same object.

`==` will be true if the values of the object are the same.

```
>>> S1 = 'HelloWorld'
>>> print id(S1)
4457604464
>>> S2 = 'HelloWorld'
>>> print id(S2)
4457604464
>>> S1 is S2
True
```

The above code means `S1` and `S2` are same object.And they have the same memory location.So `S1` is `S2`.

```
>>> S1 = 'Hello World'
>>> S2 = 'Hello World'
>>> print id(S1)
4457604320
>>> print id(S2)
4457604272
>>> S1 is S2
False
```

Now,they're different object,so `S1` is not `S2`.

Comment: >>>S1 = 'Hello World'
>>>S2 = 'Hello World'
>>>S1 is S2
False                              ----- i think the result is True,why it is False

Comment: @Sigma65535 because `S1` and `S2` are *not the same object*.

Comment: Than earlier, when there is no space between Hello and world, why they have same id?

Comment: @ChandaKorat Read the info about string interning in Daniel Pryden's answer in the linked question. Sometimes you get interning, sometimes you don't. Interning is mainly designed for caching valid Python identifiers (eg, the names of variables and attributes), so strings that could be valid identifiers are more likely to be interned.

Comment: @PM2Ring yeah thanks...!!