# Clarity on input and is

Tags: python

```
 >>>name = "lucy"
 >>>name is "lucy"
 >>>True
 >>>name=input()
 lucy
 >>>name is "lucy"
 False
```

I know that `is` checks for object identity. But isn't the object identity of name and "lucy" same here?

Also, why does assigning "lucy" to name results as True, whereas entering "lucy" as input and then assigning it to name results in False?

Comment: It is likely due to [string interning](http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/), for example [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning)

Comment: I also had used single quotes. I'm still getting the same result. Version of Python is 3.5.3

Comment: Here you have a couple of questions that might answer yours: [Python Interpreter String Pooling Optimization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364044/python-interpreter-string-pooling-optimization), [When does python choose to intern a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622472/when-does-python-choose-to-intern-a-string)

Comment: I'm double checking, when copy paste exactly this then get False; but when do this: >>> n = 'a'
>>> n is 'a'
True
>>> n=input()
a
>>> n is 'a'
True

Comment: @CoryKramer There is no link attached in your comment. Could you please send the link of whatever you'd like me to read?

Comment: Have really no clue, but when use variable name of 1 letter it results in true, when variable name longer in False
`
>>> var = 'abc'
>>> var is 'abc'
True
>>> var = input()
abc
>>> var is 'abc'
False
>>> w='n'
>>> w is 'n'
True
>>> w=input()
n
>>> w is 'n'
True
>>>`

Comment: @Drako Same here. Going through the links provided by CoryKramer. I hope I'll be able to come up with an answer after reading. :)

Comment: @CarlesMitjans I think your comment can go as answer here :) That makes sense and at same time no; now I'm scared to compare strings :)